# Facebook graph - how to regenerate user access token through PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to search Facebook for relevant groups depending on keywords. I'm using to graph explorer and it works fine.

search?&type=group&q=php&access_token=MY_TOKEN

Is there anyway I can perform this search from my server using a (my) user access token and keep renewing the access token through the PHP SDK?

From looking at the documentation it looks like I have to use a user access token that requires a login and expires after a set amount of time?

Comment: The documentation is correct. The user needs to login to extend it

Comment: Ah OK. So the search can't be performed by the app in anyway? Can't understand why they'd set the api like that

Answer (score 0):

As the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) here say . you will have to extend the token when it expires . i guess its a security measure from facebook to ensure that the user is still active with the app .

> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point,
>   you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to
>   the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not
>   actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app,
>   so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow
>   with a refreshed token

A long lived access token is valid for 60 days . All you need is to supply the new access token once in a while to your php script . ( assuming you are just using your token for performing the search )

Comment: A long-lived access token is valid for 60 days.